# How to solve the following linear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble solving the following differential equation:

$y'(x)=\frac{8A^2x}{(1+4A^2x^2)^2}\cdot y-4Bx$

$A$ and $B$ are real constants.

I would be very grateful for any help. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

A problem in classical mechanics led me to the Hamiltonian

$\mathfrak{H}=\frac{{p_r}^2}{2m(1+4a^2r^2)}+\frac{{p_{\phi}}^2}{2mr^2}+mgar^2$.

Therefore, I get $\dot{p_r}=-\frac{\partial \mathfrak{H}}{\partial r}$ and
$\dot{p_{\phi}}=-\frac{\partial \mathfrak{H}}{\partial \phi}$.

This yields $\dot{p_{\phi}}=0\Rightarrow p_{\phi}=$const.

and

$\dot{p_r}=\frac{8ra^2{p_r}^2}{2m{(1+4a^2r^2)}^2}+\frac{{p_{\phi}}^2}{mr^3}-2mgar$.

If we assume $\dot{\phi}=0$, what we will from now on, then it follows that $p_{\phi}=0$ and we get the simpler Hamiltonian
$\mathfrak{H}=\frac{{p_r}^2}{2m{(1+4a^2r^2)}^2}+mgar^2$

and

$\dot{p_r}=\frac{4ra^2{p_r}^2}{m{(1+4a^2r^2)}^2}-2mgar$.

Since $\dot{p_r}=m\dot{(\dot{r})}$, we get

$\dot{(\dot{r})}=\frac{4ra^2{\dot{r}}^2}{{(1+4a^2r^2)}^2}-2\cdot g\cdot a \cdot r$.

Let $z:=r$ and $A:=a$ and $B:=g\cdot a$.

Then we get

$z''=\frac{4zA^2{(z')}^2}{{(1+4A^2z^2)}^2}-2\cdot B \cdot z$.

We have $z''=\frac{dz'}{dt}=\frac{dz'}{dz} \cdot \frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{d}{dz}({(z')}^2)$.

Set $p:=z'$. Then we get

$\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{d}{dz}({p}^2)=\frac{4zA^2{p}^2}{{(1+4A^2z^2)}^2}-2\cdot B \cdot z$

This finally led me to the problem

$y'(x)=\frac{8A^2x}{(1+4A^2x^2)^2}\cdot y-4Bx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend starting with the linear problem

$\tilde{y}′(x)=\underbrace{\frac{8A2x}{(1+4A2x^2)^2}}_{=:M(x)}⋅\tilde{y}(t)$

using a separation

$ \frac{d\tilde{y}}{\tilde{y}} = M(x) dx $

to get $\tilde{y} = e^{c + \int M(x) dx}$

From this solution you can use [basic techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Systems_of_Linear_Differential_Equations) to get an answer for the actual problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a simple way to express $\int M(x) dx$ in terms of elementary functions?

Comment: there should be a neat closed form. Try substituting $2+4A2x^2=u$, then the $x$ in the numerator will cancel out when you replace $dx$ with $du$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Check [Riccati differential equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation).

Comment: What's the down vote for?

Comment: Does the down vote change the facts?

Comment: Because of a typing error, I had to change my question a bit, such that the considered DE is not of the form Riccati anymore...but nontheless I wanted to say thank you for your answer.

Comment: @SteinChen: You are welcome.